# Angular Scope Usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am a beginner in AngularJS.

I am working through some code of an expert.
I would like to customize the directive and learn something.

The expert always insert:

```
this.scope = $scope;
```

in the first line of every controller.

What's the point of this statement, if you later always just use `$scope`.

Comment: This means your app manipulates controller instances. You can sometimes be passed a controller instance: when using "Controller as" syntax see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController (ctrl-as-exmpl). Also, when defining controller for directives. I'm not knowledgeable about the advantages of doing things this way so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` pointer was referring to `$scope` instead of the controller.

### **this**

- When the controller constructor function is called, this is the controller.
- When a function defined on a $scope object is called, this is the "scope in effect when
  the function was called". This may (or may not!) be the $scope that the function is defined on. **So, inside the function, this and $scope may not be the same.

### **$scope**

- Every controller has an associated $scope object.
- A controller (constructor) function is responsible for setting model properties and functions/behavior on its associated $scope.
- Only methods defined on this $scope object (and parent scope objects, if prototypical inheritance is in play) are accessible from the HTML/view. E.g., from ng-click, filters, etc.

courtesy of [Mark Rajcok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215945/mark-rajcok) taken from **[How does 'this' and $scope work in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/1575570)**

**without** `this`

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.doStuff = function(){
    //Really long function body
  };
});
```

**with** `this`

```
var MyCtrl = function($scope){
  var _this = this;

  $scope.doStuff = function(){
    _this.doStuff();
  };
};

MyCtrl.prototype.doStuff = function(){
  //Really long function body
};

MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I will continue using just `$scope` until I really need `this`.